# Button link to a specific page woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a button "Order more" besides "add to cart" and it takes me one step back.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'my_function_sample', 10 );

function my_function_sample() {
  global $product;
  echo '<button type="button" onclick="history.go(-1)";> Bestil mere </button>'; 
}
```

I would like the "order more" button to direct me to a specific page instead.

I have tried to change `onclick="location.href='http://eventmad.dk/?product_cat=dhl'` but i get an syntax error.

Comment: Have you tried proper quoting to avoid the syntax error?

Comment: I think so. Here is how i wrote it: echo ' <button type="button" onclick="location.href='http://eventmad.dk/?product_cat=dhl'";> Bestil mere </button> ';

Comment: And where are your single quotes quoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote single quotes if you use them within an echo. Otherwise, PHP does not know how to handle the ended string. Try the following:

```
echo ' <button type="button" onclick="location.href=\'http://eventmad.dk/?product_cat=dhl\'"> Bestil mere </button>
```